# ASP.NET application, user communication

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I work on a asp.net web app on which users can create an account, login and play chess between them.

My question is, how should i make them communicate, for ex: if one user moves a pawn to B4, how does his opponent recognize the move? Should I do that through database queries? use a DB in which one inserts the move and the other one selects it and updates the interface?

Comment: You could use SignalR to notify the other party.

Comment: you can use file or db to store moves and call ajax to fetch new moves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many ways to do this:

1. You can store all move history in database table and have thread witch read from table and update the table when player do move.
2. You can store all move in files on server and do pretty much the same.
3. You can use [SignaR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) framework to create online session between players